# MySQL: WHERE IN any of subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, in-subquery

How to restructure this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl t
WHERE (
       t.id IN <subquery1>
    OR t.id IN <subquery2>
    OR t.id IN <subquery3>
)
```

... into something that looks more like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl t
WHERE t.id IN (<subquery1> OR <subquery2> OR <subquery3>)
```

Note: all 3 subqueries select from the same `tbl t`, but they select a *different column each*.

To clarify the subqueries a bit further with some concrete examples:

- subquery1: `SELECT col1 FROM tbl WHERE value=100`
- subquery2: `SELECT col2 FROM tbl WHERE value=200`
- subquery3: `SELECT col3 FROM tbl WHERE value=300`

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id      INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY,
    col1    INTEGER   not null,
    col2    INTEGER   not null,
    col3    INTEGER   not null,
    value   INTEGER   not null
);
```

Comment: *Note: all 3 subqueries select from the same table t, but they select a different column each.* If you use `t.id IN <subquery>` then each subquery returns only one column. What do you mean when you tell "different column"?

Comment: You may use `WHERE t.id IN (<subquery1> UNION ALL <subquery2> UNION ALL <subquery3>)`, but I doubt that this will improve.

Comment: @Akina Indeed, they return 1 column each, so 3 subqueries return 3 different columns (col1, col2, col3) respectively.

Comment: Upload your subquerys and your table structure and maybe we can help. I think you may rewrite your subqueries to have just one (or use UNION ALL) as @Akina says

Comment: The names of the columns means nothing. And I agree with @nacho - provide complete DDLs and precise queries texts. Also the query may be improved while rewrite to WHERE EXISTS.

Comment: Maybe `join` instead of `in`?

Comment: Does `table` in the query and in all 3 subqueries is the same table?

Comment: @fadlikidd Million join million 3 times == hang.

Comment: @Akina I think `UNION` might be better because you don't need to worry about duplicate and condiction is `or`.

Comment: @Akina , ah well that could be a problem.. but if the subqueries already limited to a few certain values, that might be different right? In any case, we all are curious about the subqueries

Comment: IMHO, `union` or `union all` , this need execution plan to decide which one is better, but I'll guess if subquery return few rows and main table have a lot of rows than `union` might be faster, on the contrary, `union all`

Comment: @T.Peter I doubt strongly. `WHERE IN (.. UNION ALL ..)` causes combining and sorting rowsets whereas `WHERE IN (.. UNION ALL ..)` additionally removes duplicates. Average compacting factor is 2 which gives one additional binary search step over sorted rowset. In general the profit of the compactization is less than the overhead of duplicate removing. From the other side UNION instead of UNION ALL may make sense when each separate subquery returns huge percent of duplicates and compacting factor is high enough (approx. over 20).

Comment: agree, subquery have to return huge amount of duplicate for actual impact.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to restructure? How many rows in table , how many rows in each sub query.?

Comment: What is the approximate amount of rows: in the table, returned by each subquery, returned by the query? *Table structure* And no indices?

Comment: @Akina The table has indices on `id`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`. The size of the table is very large (millions of records), however the subqueries return a small amount (<10 of records).

Comment: The index `(value, colX)` may improve.

Comment: ' very large (millions of records); - doesn't say much. 2 million is millions but not very large.

Comment: @P.Salmon ~41 million roughly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested a lot of variants (synthetic table, 10kk rows, colX = random in 1..10kk, value = random in 1..1kk). The most fast is:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON test (value);
```

```sql
SELECT id
FROM test
WHERE id in (SELECT col1 FROM test WHERE value = 100)
UNION
SELECT id
FROM test
WHERE id in (SELECT col2 FROM test WHERE value = 200)
UNION
SELECT id
FROM test
WHERE id in (SELECT col3 FROM test WHERE value = 1000)
ORDER BY id;
```

---

```
mysql> SELECT id
    -> FROM test
    -> WHERE id in (SELECT col1 FROM test WHERE value = 100)
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT id
    -> FROM test
    -> WHERE id in (SELECT col2 FROM test WHERE value = 200)
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT id
    -> FROM test
    -> WHERE id in (SELECT col3 FROM test WHERE value = 1000)
    -> ORDER BY id;
-- <output skipped>
36 rows in set (1.60 sec)

mysql> SELECT id
    -> FROM test
    -> WHERE (
    ->    id in (SELECT col1 FROM test WHERE value = 100)
    ->    OR
    ->    id in (SELECT col2 FROM test WHERE value = 200)
    ->    OR
    ->    id in (SELECT col3 FROM test WHERE value = 1000)
    -> )
    -> ORDER BY id;
-- <output skipped>
36 rows in set (29.18 sec)
```

Comment: This query is a better representation of the problem asked by the OP. (mae).

Answer (score 4):

A quick test on a table `integers` with only the field `i` (and 2621441 rows):

```
SELECT i 
FROM integers
WHERE (
   i in (SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 100)
   OR
   i in (SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 200)
   OR 
   i in (SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 1000)
)
ORDER BY i;

+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | integers | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL  | 2615753 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  4 | SUBQUERY    | integers | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | integers | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | integers | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Above returns result in about 2 secs.

```
SELECT i 
FROM integers
WHERE i in (
   SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 100
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 200
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 1000
)
ORDER BY i;

+----+--------------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | integers | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL  | 2615753 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | integers | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT UNION    | integers | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  4 | DEPENDENT UNION    | integers | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+--------------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Above returns results in about 1.35 sec

```
SELECT i 
FROM integers
WHERE i in (
   SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 100
   UNION
   SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 200
   UNION 
   SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i = 1000
)
ORDER BY i;

+----+--------------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | integers     | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL  | 2615753 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | integers     | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT UNION    | integers     | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  4 | DEPENDENT UNION    | integers     | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |       1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
| NULL | UNION RESULT       | <union2,3,4> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |    NULL |     NULL | Using temporary          |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
5 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Above returns results in 1.6 secs.

The 'winner' is `UNION ALL`

Comment: @mae The problem with this accepted answer is I have no idea which of the 2 choices is being accepted or why - ergo not very useful to forum Can you please give your reason for acceptance.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it can be done with one subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl t1
WHERE t1.id IN (
  SELECT  
    CASE t2.value
        WHEN 100 THEN t2.col1
        WHEN 200 THEN t2.col2
        WHEN 1000 THEN t2.col3
    END AS id
  FROM tbl t2
  WHERE t2.value IN (100, 200, 1000)
)
```

Tested on 2474003 rows with index `v4` on `value` column:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type  | table       | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL               | NULL |   100.00 | NULL                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | t1          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | <subquery2>.id     |    1 |   100.00 | Using where           |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | t2          | NULL       | range  | v4            | v4      | 4       | NULL               |    7 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Or without subqueries. If `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are a subset of `id`, then the subquery is the answer itself.